# Pandas - multiply column values by dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of football stats with scaled values, like so:

```
team match Gls  Ast  SoT Sha Crs Fls
Arg  987.  0.11 0.04 0.8 0.5 0.2 0.65
....
```

Now I would like to apply weights to each value, according to the following dictionary:

```
weights = {
    'Gls':8,
    'Ass':5,
    'SoT':1.5,
    'Sha':1.3,
    'Crs':1.2,
    'Fld':1.2
}
```

Each dict value is scalar to be multiplied by its correpondent column value.

How do I approach this using `apply()` in pandas?

Comment: Create a frame with the dict, protect other columns using `set_index` then perform the operation using `mul`. That will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an approach with melt:

```
weights = {
    'Gls':8,
    'Ass':5,
    'SoT':1.5,
    'Sha':1.3,
    'Crs':1.2,
    'Fld':1.2
}

(df
 .melt(id_vars=['team', 'match'])
 .assign(new=lambda x: x.value * x.variable.map(weights))
)
```

or with set_index:

```
(df
 .set_index(['team', 'match'])
 .mul(weights)
 .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this code doesn't depend on `apply()`, it should work as you outlined:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=(
        ("Arg", 987., 0.11, 0.04, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.65),
    ),
    columns=("team", "match", "Gls", "Ast", "SoT", "Sha", "Crs", "Fls")
)
weights = {
    'Gls': 8,
    'Ast': 5,
    'SoT': 1.5,
    'Sha': 1.3,
    'Crs': 1.2,
    'Fls': 1.2
}
for column in set(df.columns) & set(weights):
    df.loc[:, column] = df.loc[:, column].mul(weights[column])
```

That results in:

```
  team  match   Gls  Ast  SoT   Sha   Crs   Fls
0  Arg  987.0  0.88  0.2  1.2  0.65  0.24  0.78
```